# Google CacheService putAll() not working where put does

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm experiencing issues with CacheService.getScriptCache().putAll().

The array is ~7k small strings (~50char), if I execute the following code it's very slow but it works.

```
function updateCache(sheet, range, cache){
  var contents = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
  var db = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    var tmp = contents[i][0]==""? "empty":contents[i][0];
    db[tmp] = i;
    cache.put(tmp, i, 86400);
  }
  //cache.putAll(db, 86400);
}
```

If i comment the put method and enable the putAll line i have the following error:

> Spiacenti. Si è verificato un errore del server. Attendi e riprova.

The problem is very general and I can't understand why it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: As noted in documentation, `CacheService` is for `String`s: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putkey-value See also this question and its answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35744241/9337071

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have ever experienced the same situation with you before. At that time, when `putAll()` is used, if the numbers were included in the values of the object, such error occurred. On the other hand, `put()` can be used. I could remove the error by converting the number to the string. Because when I put the number using `put()`, the retrieved value became the string. I could notice this solution by this. So in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From :

```
db[tmp] = i;
```

#### To :

```
db[tmp] = i.toString();
```

or

```
db[tmp] = String(i);
```

If this was not the solution for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Tanaike is correct. The values you want to store should be strings. There is another way to ensure that the values are converted; use `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()`. The former automatically converts cell values to strings.

Comment: @Dimu Designs Thank you for adding the information.