# Google app script, cacheServices and cache.get need promises to work?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[Here is the code that wrote but doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT8A9.jpg)

I am trying to make a telegram bot in google app script. When the user types /start. There will be a prompt to set start from null to true in the cacheServices(I was wondering is there a better way to store variables that don't change, because if i put a start variable as "False" and override in the code it will become a False again after running).

To further elaborate, i set a login variable to be true manually and it worked perfectly. So just need some direction to wait for the cache to load before executing code!

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: Code goes in the question and not in an image.

Comment: CacheService is not for arbitrary objects - it is only for `String`s. This is stated in the method signature: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#put(String,String) . See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35744241/9337071

Answer (score 0):

Oh i realised if i change the from a boolean to a string for setting the values it will work. So for example instead of the key,value pair of ["start":true], ["start":"true"] and start=="true" will work. Still don't know why booleans dont work.